# Magento2 - Updating a list of stock items using REST (batch update)

Tags: magento2, api, custom, rest-api

I have built a custom module that will save a single stock item via **REST API** (similar to what is already available) - however, how would this be done with multiple stock items within the same request (like a batch update).  I've tried to make the `@param an /../../inventoryItem[]` in my method definition in the module/api folder, but it doesn't seem to work.

I see we can't simply send an array as we could in **Magento 1**.

the structure would be something like

```
{"inventory":[{"sku"=>"some_sku", "qty"=>10}, {"sku"=>"some_sku2", "qty"=>12}]}.
```

If someone could lead me over this architecturally - especially with the interfaces/classes required, then that would be helpful.

I assume I'd need such classes (as below) - one for the inventory object, another for the array - but I haven't worked extensively with interfaces and having trouble defining things in a Magento way.

```
<?php

class InventoryObject {

    private $sku;
    private $qty;

    public function __construct($sku, $qty) {
        $this->qty = $qty;
        $this->sku = $sku;
    }

    public function getQty(){
        return $this->qty;
    }

    public function setQty($qty){
        $this->qty = $qty;
    }

    public function getSku(){
        return $this->sku;
    }

    public function setSku($sku){
        $this->sku = $sku;
    }

}

class InventoryObjectArray {

    private $inventoryObject = array();

    public function __construct(InventoryObject $io) {
        $this->inventoryObject[] = $io;     
    }


    public function setInventoryObject(InventoryObject $io) {
        $this->inventoryObject[] = $io; 
    }

    public function getInventoryObject() {

        return $this->inventoryObject;      
    }

}
```

then after this, I can loop through and save stock items one by one.  Do I need to define this?
Or just use the standard **stockitem** object and pass into an array?
In any case, bit confused and need assistance structuring things properly.

Comment: are you able to share the module - would be helpful to know how this is done :) Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like all already ready for you in Magento.

You need only one file in your module `etc/webapi.xml` with content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/stockItems" method="GET">
        <service class="\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStatusRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

```
<?php
class StockStatusRepository implements \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStatusRepositoryInterface
{
    ....

    /**
     * @param  \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface[] $stockItems
     * @return bool
     */ 
    public function batchUpdate($stockItems)
    {
        foreach ($stockItems as $items) {
            $this->stockItemRepo->save($stockItems);
        }
        return true; 
     }
}
```

And all your work will be done.

Comment: Hi KAndy, thanks for the response but I meant loading and saving inventory in batch - not retrieving.  I'll update my question so it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks KAndy, this was helpful - I will need to adapt this to update by SKU but a good start - thanks for revising answer.

Comment: @KAndy so where does the `StockStatusRepository` belong? And how would you call this custom endpoint? This is for modifying the stock levels so why would it be using `method="GET"` - should be using `PUT` surely?

Comment: Guys, is there appeared any module for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In the end i created my own stock object and declared it in the `phpdoc` for the API method as
**@param MyCo\MyClass\Api\Data\StockItems[] $stockItems.**

which translates to

```
{stockItems:[{product_id:id, quantity:0},.. etc ..]}
```

I then iterated through the StockItems array, adding inventory with an injected Magento stockitem object.

It is working now at least.

Comment: can you please share the code what you have achieved

Comment: It would be nice to have the module! Thx in advance.