# Add multiple products in single API call in magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have to migrate data from RMS to magento. There are thousands of records that needs to be migrated. I am using REST API to save product.

```
http://localhost:89/index.php/rest/all/V1/products
```

This is the API url to add prduct.

```
    {
  "product": {
        "sku": "B201-SKU",
        "name": "B202",
        "price": 30.00,
        "status": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "attribute_set_id":4,
        "weight": 1
    }
}
```

This is the sample payload. Is it possible to pass multiple product information to this request. If yes, please provide some example.

Thanks
Jawed

Comment: Guys. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The current Magento 2.1 REST api only supports single object calls. Magento 2.2 will support bulk updates of (tiered) prices, but that's all there's available for now.

If you want to perform bulk calls, you would need to extend the Magento 2 api with a custom controller, that is able to handle calls with multiple entities. This question on [updating multiple stock entries](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119414/magento2-updating-a-list-of-stock-items-using-rest-batch-update) is a good starting pointing.

For some more information, check out this Github issue from March 2015, which still resembles the current state: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1079

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3 now has bulk API that can be used for creating products in bulk. Please see link below:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/bulk-configurable-product/config-product-intro.html